# Is there a concise way to return a value used to round a number, if the number is between a given range?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to round a number up, but rounded to a value dependent on the numbers magnitude.

I have the following code, but it does not allow for returning a number that can be used for rounding when the number is of absolutely any magnitude and it is also very repetitive.

Is there a way that this could be refactored in a more concise way?

```js
const roundingResolution = (max: number): number => {
  if (max > 0.1 && max <= 0.5) return 0.05;
  if (max > 0.5 && max <= 1) return 0.1;
  if (max > 1 && max <= 5) return 0.5;
  if (max > 5 && max <= 10) return 1;
  if (max > 10 && max <= 50) return 5;
  if (max > 50 && max <= 100) return 10;
  if (max > 100 && max <= 500) return 50;
  if (max > 500 && max <= 1000) return 100;
  if (max > 1000 && max <= 5000) return 500;
  if (max > 5000 && max <= 10000) return 1000;
  if (max > 10000 && max <= 50000) return 5000;
  if (max > 50000 && max <= 100000) return 10000;
  return 1;
};

const resolution = roundingResolution(value);

const roundedValue = Math.ceil(value / resolution) * resolution;
```

Comment: You have a separate problem. You only test `>` and `<`, but never match when the value is exactly `==` to one of the boundaries.

Comment: Could you not try an iterative or recursive attempt here? Also I don't think your conditionals will work as expected, 1,5,10,50...50000, you use less than 5, more than 5, but not 5, the same with the other examples. There is a pattern to your logic, multiples of 5 and 10, you could try use of a modulas operator.

Comment: @Barmar - true! Thanks and updated

Comment: @Mr. Robot that's not fixed, you only need to check greater than or equal to in one part, else both conditions are true

Comment: Thanks @Isolated! Good spot.

Comment: What if `max` is `9102391823817234823481712784`?

Comment: @Justinas - yes - exactly.

Comment: and maybe you shouldn't return 0 from roundingResolution(), if you want the result to be a divisor ;)

Comment: Yes thanks @Agree, but I have to return something and safer to return 0 then anything else? Ideally I can find a solution that accounts for any number

Comment: @Mr.Robot Return `1` as you can't divide by 0

Comment: @Justinas - updated :)

Comment: This solution in your answers works, also is a lot faster than iteration/recursion, I tested it with 9102391823817234823481712784 and got 1e+27, so 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 you can work out it that's accurate or not.

Answer (score 2):

roundingResolution can write in a more generic way like in the code below:

```
var roundingResolution = (max: number): number => {
    if (max <= 0.1 || max > A_max_number) return 1; //?
    var logValue = Math.log10(max);
    var base = Math.floor(logValue);
    var pow10 = Math.pow(10, base);
    var mod = max/pow10;
    if( mod > 5)
    {
        return pow10;
    } else
    { 
        return pow10/2;
    }
}
```

The idea is to get mod and base from the formula: max = mod * 10^base

Comment: Thanks @Linh Nguyen, but if `max` is 3, then it returns 0.5 and if `max` is 4 then it returns 1 which is not the same as my example.

Comment: @Mr.Robot sorry, I was too quick. I just updated the calculation and added an explaination

Answer (score 2):

Use `math.log10()` to get the magnitude of the number, and then compare to the multiples of `5` and `10` at that magnitude, returning the appropriate ceiling.

```js
const roundingResolution = (max) => {
  let pow10 = Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(max)));
  if (max < pow10 / 2) {
    return pow10 / 20;
  } else {
    return pow10/10;
  }
}

console.log(roundingResolution(700));
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmer, but the result seems to be off by a factor of 10?

Comment: I didn't notice that you were dividing by 10 in your results. So it's not really rounding the number.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to making this more concise I'd recommend doing this following:

```
const roundingResolution = (max: number): number => {
  if (max > 0.1 && max <= 0.5) return 0.05;
  if (max <= 1) return 0.1;
  if (max <= 5) return 0.5;
  if (max <= 10) return 1;
  if (max <= 50) return 5;
  if (max <= 100) return 10;
  if (max <= 500) return 50;
  if (max <= 1000) return 100;
  if (max <= 5000) return 500;
  if (max <= 10000) return 1000;
  if (max <= 50000) return 5000;
  if (max <= 100000) return 10000;
  return 1;
};

const resolution = roundingResolution(value);

const roundedValue = Math.ceil(value / resolution) * resolution;
```

You can do this where you don't check if values are between a range since the range up until each fi statement is escaped thanks to the `return` statement.

You could shorten this further by looping the if statements if there is a specific pattern, but this is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about the semantics I just refactored your code I guess that's what you wanted.

```js
const roundingResolution = max => {
  function* ranges() {
    let x = 0.1;
    while (true) {
      yield [x, x * 5];
      x *= 5;
      yield [x, x * 2];
      x *= 2;
    }
  }
  
  let threshold = 100000;
  for (let [lower, upper] of ranges()) {
    if (upper > threshold) return 1;
    if (max > lower && max <= upper) {
      return upper / 5;
    }
  }
}

console.log(roundingResolution(52))
```

You could have the `threshold` to be `Infinity` but your ranges have gaps for example `7` would result in infinite loop.

(testing:)

```js
function* ranges() {
  let x = 0.1;
  while (true) {
    yield [x, x * 5];
    x *= 5;
    yield [x, x * 2];
    x *= 2;
  }
}

for (let [lower, upper] of ranges()) {
  if (upper > 10000) break;
  console.log(`max < ${lower} && max <= ${upper}`)
}
```